# How do I pass variables to other methods using Python's click (Command Line Interface Creation Kit) package

Tags: python, python-click

I know it's new, but I like the look of [click](http://click.pocoo.org/) a lot and would love to use it, but I can't work out how to pass variables from the main method to other methods. Am I using it incorrectly, or is this functionality just not available yet? Seems pretty fundamental, so I'm sure it will be in there, but this things only been out a [little while](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click) so maybe not.

```
import click

@click.option('--username', default='', help='Username')
@click.option('--password', default='', help='Password')
@click.group()
def main(**kwargs):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(kwargs))


@main.command('do_thingy')
def do_thing(**kwargs):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(kwargs))


@main.command('do_y')
def y(**kwargs):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(kwargs))


@main.command('do_x')
def x(**kwargs):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(kwargs))


main()
```

So my question is, how do I get the username and password options to be available to the other methods

Comment: I cannot help you. Just want to propose you to consider looking at `docopt` command line parser.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks to @nathj07 for pointing me in the right direction. Here's the answer:

```
import click


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


@click.group()
@click.option('--username', default='Naomi McName', help='Username')
@click.option('--password', default='b3$tP@sswerdEvar', help='Password')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, username, password):
    ctx.obj = User(username, password)
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(username) + ", " + str(password))


@main.command()
@click.pass_obj
def do_thingy(ctx):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(ctx.username) + ", " + str(ctx.password))


@main.command()
@click.pass_obj
def do_y(ctx):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(ctx.username) + ", " + str(ctx.password))


@main.command()
@click.pass_obj
def do_x(ctx):
    print("This method has these arguments: " + str(ctx.username) + ", " + str(ctx.password))


main()
```

Answer (score -8):

Is there any reason you can't use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)? I should think it would allow you to achieve what you are looking for, though in a slightly different manner.

As for using click then [perhaps the pass_obj will help](http://click.pocoo.org/complex/#complex-guide) you out

Comment: @Julius but you got subparses which is another approach to the similar functionality